# Use django admin to save a list of selected objects to another table

Tags: django, admin

I am new to Django. I have two database tables where one contains a list of medications and the other contains a list of patients.

I want to select a group of medications and add them to individual patients in the patients table.

Can i use a custom action in django admin to achieve this?
How can this be done, kindly explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're going to want to do here is set up your Patient and Medication models (if you have them) to be linked to each other using Django's [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/), or [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) systems in your `models.py`. So for example, a Patient model could have a one-to-many, many-to-many, or one-to-one relationship with the Medication model, depending on how you personally would like to have your project set up.

When doing this, if you want to see/create patients and medications in your admin interface, you could simply do `admin.site.register(Patient)` or `admin.site.register(Medication)` in your `admin.py`, of course not forgetting to `import` them first.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried it this weekend and it worked like magic. Thanks a great deal.

Comment: @user6417220 Hey glad I could help! I had the exact same issue once upon a time. If the answer was what you were looking for you can accept it and it will show that your question has a solution if others were to find it.